# Persisting Client IP address in rest apis deployed in AKS

Tags: kubernetes, networking, azure-aks

Persisting Client IP address in rest apis deployed in AKS.
Is there any setup to be done at AKS level to persist client IP address?
Currently AKS cluster ip is assigned to client IP address in meta data info of header.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to preserve the client IP for incoming requests, have you tried setting the `externalTrafficPolicy` to `Local` on the Service?

Here is a walkthrough of that type of setup.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/fasttrack-for-azure/how-client-source-ip-preservation-works-for-loadbalancer/ba-p/3033722

Comment: Yes paul i tried that approach already & it didnt help me.

Comment: The blog explains to set it to Local on application level, but the IP Address is already obscured by ingress controller, so it shows the IP of LoadBalancer service in ingress controller. Also Local can cause imbalance in traffic, thats what I have read. Did you find some other solution to it?